# Should I choose Web Site or Web Application?

Tags: asp.net, .net

When I want to start a new ASP.Net project in Visual Studio 2012 but I'm given the option to create an ASP.NET Web Application or an ASP.NET Web Site.

What's the difference between the two ASP.NET Web Application and ASP.NET Web Sites? I've developed Web Sites before but never tried a Web Application and would like to know more.

Comment: Quick google search should help with that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Who upvoted this. It's clearly someone who didn't bother to do any research before asking the question, and it's a fairly basic one. Just read the intro docs on the two types of projects.

Comment: Do not ever use Web Site "projects" if you can help it. They are different from every other project type in Visual Studio, and IMO represent a feature designed by the marketing department.

Answer (score -1):

This has already been answered... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959910/web-site-vs-web-application) and this will also help.. [here](http://www.visionmobile.com/blog/2013/07/web-sites-vs-web-apps-what-the-experts-think/)

Comment: So, why didn't you vote to close as a duplicate?

Comment: I forgot that I had that ability. My bad.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you do _not_ have that ability until 3,000.

Comment: Makes sense why I couldn't do it. And sad about the downvote. haha

Comment: @Humpy even without the ability to close vote it still isn't a great answer as it's just links, no explanation. I would post something like this in the comments if I didn't have the rep to close as duplicate.

Comment: I made a comment about doing a google search, wasn't positive if he'd see it, knew he'd see an answer(if he checks back), even if it doesn't explain the answer in great depth, he'd get the idea that searching before asking would be best.